# Need consistent Bootstrap form inputs across browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

I have a grid of input fields on my form.  Bootstrap is naturally adding a bit of horizontal space between the fields in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzIgh.jpg), which is how I want the form to look, but the fields are getting jammed together in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSvSt.jpg).  In the Firefox image above, I have highlighted the `col-md-2` `div` in Firebug which wraps the input field.  The `input` field is highlighted in Chrome.

This seems to be the difference - Firefox seems to be constraining the input fields to fit inside the grid elements, but this is not the case in Chrome.  In Firefox, the input fields in the grid are 144 px wide but in Chrome they are 170 px wide.

Here is the markup for a row of fields:

```
<div class="row signup">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <span class="plus-icon">
            <img width="18" height="18" src="/assets/plus.jpg" alt="Plus">
        </span>

        <span class="minus-icon">
            <img width="18" height="18" src="/assets/minus.jpg" alt="Minus">
        </span>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="sheet_slots_attributes_0_label" type="text" name="sheet[slots_attributes][0][label]" value="Food">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="sheet_slots_attributes_0_name" type="text" name="sheet[slots_attributes][0][name]" value="Foo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="sheet_slots_attributes_0_email" type="text" name="sheet[slots_attributes][0][email]" value="foo@foo.com">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="sheet_slots_attributes_0_phone" type="text" name="sheet[slots_attributes][0][phone]" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="sheet_slots_attributes_0_comments" type="text" name="sheet[slots_attributes][0][comments]" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to build a fiddle to demonstrate this but I am not able to get it working.  So sorry for no fiddle, but I thought someone may have seen this before.

FYI the `row signup` markup is just adding bottom margin to space out the rows a bit.  Also, I've tried adding an extra `col-md-1` to get to an even 12 both at the start and end of each row but it doesn't help.  I don't have any extra markup for any of this - just using Bootstrap.

It would be great to also understand why the input boxes look relatively ugly (squarish and plain) on Chrome as well - perhaps this is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the width of the inputs to 100%. This makes them take up the width of their container. Otherwise, you are letting the browser determine the default width of the inputs. You can do this manually, or add the bootstrap class `form-control` to each input.

[See it in action in this demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ubi3ZJIpSI)

Comment: OK that deserves (at least) the upvote - thanks Ted.  For me `form-control` made the inputs very narrow and a bit too tall.  100% width works, but the inputs are still a bit narrow.  I seemed to be able to solve that by tweaking the width (looks great for all browsers at 115%).  Anything dangerous about that approach?  Also, any idea why my input boxes look so pretty in FF, and so stark in Chrome (and IE)?  Am I missing or overriding some other styling?

Comment: Then I think your problem is with the width of the gutters in bootstrap. You can customize bootstrap on their site to have narrower gutters. The risk in setting them to 115% is that they may overflow oddly when reduced to mobile sizes. As for styling, if you are not applying any styling, you are letting the browser decide what they should look like.

Comment: @steveklein Here you go, I [forked that bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/nuhYmr3jkK) to show adding a custom grid override to the CSS (making for much narrower gutters).

Comment: Great point on the 115% - I set it back to 100%.  When you say go to their site, do you mean I need to configure a new distribution of `bootstrap` with narrower gutters?  I am using Rails, so that is not as great as just including gems and manifest directives.

Comment: OK I see what you did there.  I should be good from here - thanks again for all of your help.  Also, great implicit tip in that bootply about using www.placehold.it for custom sized graphic placeholders!

Comment: Glad to help. yeah, www.placehold.it is a pretty handy little site :)

Comment: I've tweaked a bit and settled on using a combination of 95% input width, +/- 5px padding/margin on my `col-md-2` class, plus I added `form-control` to my inputs so they look nice cross browser.  Much much better thanks again.